# Algorithm to factorize matrix whose many rows are already of upper triangular form?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, matrix-factorization

I have a matrix whose many rows are already in the upper triangular form.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14}  & x_{5} \\
    0 & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24}  & x_{25} \\
    0 & 0 & x_{23} & x_{34}  & x_{35} \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{45} \\
    x_{51} & x_{52} & x_{53} & x_{54} & x_{55} \\
x_{61} & x_{62} & x_{63} & x_{64}  & x_{65}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Let me take an example to show that the function `scipy.linalg.lu` from package `Scipy` does not take advantage of this special structure. Here `B` is a copy of `A` with the elements below the main diagonal zeroed.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
import time
A = np.random.randint(100, size=(10000, 10000))
B = np.triu(A, 0)

start = time.time()
(P, L, U) = la.lu(A)
end = time.time()
print('Time to decompose A =', end - start)

start = time.time()
(P1, L1, U1) = la.lu(B)
end = time.time()
print('Time to decompose B =', end - start)
```

The result is

```
Time to decompose A = 5.622066497802734
Time to decompose B = 5.322663068771362
```

Because my square matrix is of very large dimension and this procedure is repeated thousands of times. I would like to ask for a method (or references) to make use of this special structure to reduce the computational complexity.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Why would you want to decompose a matrix that is already in triangular form? If $A$ is lower triangular, then the $LU$ decomposition is $A=AI$ where $L=A$, $U=I$.

Comment: Hi @WolfgangBangerth, I take this special example in Python to illustrate that `scipy.linalg.lu` does not make use of this special structure. In my problem, the matrix is not of upper triangular form, but it contains some rows of this form. I mean how to make use of the special structure of these rows.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I have edited my post to make it clearer.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/linalg.html#triangle-on-top-of-rectangle This algorithm uses a specialized QR method to factor this type of matrix, namely a modified Elmroth and Gustafson 2000 method

Comment: This also looks like you might want to read through the literature on sparse direct solvers.

Comment: @vibe It's unfortunate that the upper triangular block matrix must be a square one :((

Comment: Thank you so much for your reference @WolfgangBangerth! I will try my best.

Comment: @LAD, hmm ok I missed that your triangular matrix is not square. That would make it difficult to compute the $R$ factor in-place. So what you have is trapezoidal on top of rectangle. If you can do a small number of givens transformations to make a square triangle in top of rectangle, you can then do the efficient algorithm I referenced

Comment: @vibe I'm out of luck again. My full matrix is already square.

Comment: @LAD What that method says is that you can essentially implement QR factorization directly, skipping the entries that are known to be zero. I don't see any major difficulties in applying that also to your case, even if the dimensions are not exactly the same.

Comment: I agree with Frederico you could implement an efficient QR method for this matrix, similar to the gsl routine. However I recommend instead the LU approach in my answer below, since it is efficient and much easier to implement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish what you want efficiently using the recursive LU algorithm. In brief, recursive LU on a $M \times N$ matrix $A$ proceeds by partitioning the matrix into 4 blocks:
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22}} &= \pmatrix{L_{11} & 0 \\ L_{21} & L_{22}} \pmatrix{U_{11} & U_{12} \\ 0 & U_{22}} \\
&= \pmatrix{L_{11} U_{11} & L_{11} U_{12} \\ L_{21} U_{11} & L_{21} U_{12} + L_{22} U_{22}}
\end{align}
Then, the following 4 subproblems must be solved:

(1) $A_{11} = L_{11} U_{11}$ (recursive LU call)

(2) $A_{12} = L_{11} U_{12} \rightarrow U_{12} = L_{11}^{-1} A_{12}$ (TRSM - Level 3 BLAS)

(3) $A_{21} = L_{21} U_{11} \rightarrow L_{21} = A_{21} U_{11}^{-1}$ (TRSM - Level 3 BLAS)

(4) $A_{22} = L_{21} U_{12} + L_{22} U_{22} \rightarrow A_{22} - L_{21} U_{12} = L_{22} U_{22}$ (GEMM followed by recursive LU call)

Now normally for recursive LU, you pick the partition so that $A_{11}$ has $N/2$ columns. However, for your specialized matrix, you should pick $A_{11}$ to be a square upper triangular matrix. So basically just pick $A_{11}$ so that you cut off the trapezoidal part of the matrix, and then pick $A_{12}$ to be that extra rectangle completing the trapezoid. If you do this, then you immediately know that $L_{11} = I$ and $U_{11} = A_{11}$ and $U_{12} = A_{12}$. Then all that remains to do is steps 3 and 4:

(3) $L_{21} = A_{21} U_{11}^{-1}$ (TRSM)

(4) $A_{22} - L_{21} U_{12} = L_{22} U_{22}$ (GEMM and then use any standard LU routine, e.g. LAPACK or scipy or whatever)

If you want to also implement pivoting, then it is possible to modify the above steps to allow pivoting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I will read it carefully.

Comment: I should have mentioned, a C implementation of recursive LU can be found here: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gsl.git/tree/linalg/lu.c -- see the routine LU_decomp_L3. Of course, you don't really need a fully recursive algorithm, you are just doing the first step of the recursion, taking advantage of the special matrix structure, and then calling a conventional LU algorithm

Comment: I would like to thank you again for your dedicated help. For a student not specializing in coding and algorithm. Adjusting available algorithm is really exhausting :(((

Comment: You mentioned you are using python, which I am not too familiar with. But for step 3, it is important that you use the proper TRSM BLAS call to take advantage of the triangular structure of $U_{11}$. Hopefully python will allow you to call the appropriate low-level BLAS routines.

Comment: My professor allows me to choose Python or C, C++, or C#. I will change to C, C++, or C# if it makes my life easier.

Comment: Actually, my full problem is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696623/how-to-utilize-the-special-feature-of-this-recursive-problem-to-reduce-computati. I have to solve a system of linear equations which is very special.

Comment: I've implemented your algorithm and the result is so fantastic. For the matrix with dimension $10000 \times 10000$, your algorithm is almost $80\%$ faster than `scipy.linalg.lu`. The performance difference becomes bigger as the dimension increases. You really made my day. If I had 500 rep in this site, I would award it to you. I hope that you can post your method in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696623/how-to-utilize-the-special-feature-of-this-recursive-problem-to-reduce-computati so that I can award the 500 rep bounty to you.

Comment: You only need to copy this answer to my other post so that I can award bounty ^_^