# Why is 'scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu' less efficient than 'scipy.linalg.lu' for sparse matrix?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, scipy, matrix-factorization

I have a matrix `B` which is sparse and try to utilize a function `scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu` specialized for sparse matrix to factorize `B`. Could you please explain why this function is significantly less efficient than the function `scipy.linalg.lu` for general matrix? Thank you so much!

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
import scipy.sparse.linalg as spla
import time
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
A = np.random.randint(100, size=(10000, 10000))
B = np.triu(A, -100)

start = time.time()
(P, L, U) = la.lu(B)
end = time.time()
print('Time to decompose B with lu =', end - start)

start = time.time()
mtx = spla.spilu(csc_matrix(B))
end = time.time()
print('Time to decompose B with spilu =', end - start)
```

The computation time is

```
Time to decompose B with lu = 4.7765138149261475
Time to decompose B with spilu = 14.165712594985962
```

Comment: You are benchmarking the format conversion to a `csc_matrix` together with the algorithm; is that intended?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni If I do not use `csc_matrix`, there is a warning `SparseEfficiencyWarning: splu requires CSC matrix format warn('splu requires CSC matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)`.

Comment: @LAD Federico is talking about timing. You may want to move the conversion to `csc_matrix` outside of the timing procedure.

Comment: Ah I got it. Thank you for your clarification!

Comment: There is also the fact that you're creating a dense matrix that you then convert into the completely unsuitable CSC format.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth This is the first time I'm exposed to this problem of writing such complicated code to do my job. I mean all of the things are complete new to me :((

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular effect is highly likely to come from parallelization.

In many setups, numpy will use multiple threads for invoked BLAS/LAPACK calls.
In the default setting on my laptop (Mac OS, native Apple python):

> ```
> ('Time to decompose B with lu =', 9.530492067337036)
> ('Time to decompose B with spilu =', 20.418880939483643)
> ```

and the Activity Monitor shows multiple threads invoked during the `lu` call, and only a single one during `spilu` call.

After [explicitly specifying the number of threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31622299/2452869) (notice, on Mac you have to do [this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791550/limit-number-of-threads-in-numpy#comment85517289_31622299)) with an "overkill set of commands":

```
export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
export VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS=1
```

The timings changed for the vanilla dense LU:

> ```
> ('Time to decompose B with lu =', 25.678237199783325)
> ('Time to decompose B with spilu =', 21.03290104866028)
> ```

[This answer can also be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665619/2452869).

**General comment:**

[`scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu.html?highlight=spilu#scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu) corresponds to sparse **incomplete** LU decomposition, which is usually used as a preconditioner. Consider [using devoted sparse direct solvers](http://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scipy_sparse/solvers.html) in case it fits your needs better.

Comment: Do you mean by "devoted sparse direct solvers" that I should figure out the special structure of my matrix and look for a solver dedicated for this structure?

Comment: @LAD not necesserily. I mean to use, say, [`scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html). or [`scipy.sparse.linalg.splu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.splu.html) if you need the factorization. As `spilu` is not intended to be used out of the preconditioner realm in most cases. I added a link to the post, which you might find helpful.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on the module to factorize the matrix whose many rows are already of upper triangular form? $$\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14}  & x_{5} \\
    0 & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24}  & x_{25} \\
    0 & 0 & x_{23} & x_{34}  & x_{35} \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{45} \\
    x_{51} & x_{52} & x_{53} & x_{54} & x_{55} \\
x_{61} & x_{62} & x_{63} & x_{64}  & x_{65}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I've seen [your question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/35255/20688). I would first try to use standard sparse direct solvers. It might be good enough Because if you want to squeeze all juices, you might have to do a lot of manual work yourself. I would also look into doing direct interaction/configuring of PARDISO solver which I am the most familiar. Not that I know right away how to deal with your particular case, though.

Comment: Also, I would warn you that a triangular (or close to) matrix is not sparse enough to be efficient. You need much more sparsity to take advantage of it using sparse linear algebra. Otherwise, dense operations might be a better fit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated help! You exactly addressing my concern. It's impossible for me (not a CS student) to adjust the available code.